# I have a 100 threads but only 60 instances

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, threadpool, infinite-loop

I have a singleton class and a method with an endless loop. I would like to call that a hundred times with 100 threads inside getInstance. The threads are created, but I only have 60-70 object which are created by the infinite loop.
I'm open to any idea.

I've already tried with newCachedThreadPool and newFixedThreadPool.

```
public final class MyClass {

    private static MyClass instance = null;
    public static boolean stop;
    private static Map<Integer, CustomBean> pieces = new HashMap<>();

    public static MyClass getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyClass();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
                    try {
                        endlessMagic();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void endlessMagic() throws InterruptedException {

        while (!stop) {
            // where magic happens
            pieces.put(something);
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyClassServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        MyClass.getInstance();
    }

    @Override public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        MyClass.stop = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue, you're saying there's only 60-70 of your `() -> { ... endlessMagic(); ... }` Runnable created? (which wouldn't make much sense). Also, don't use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` in this case when you want to run more than just a single thread.

Comment: `HashMap` is not thread-safe. Consider using `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Oh, that object. So he's creating `something` in endless magic and probably putting some into the same keys in the map, or racing to put, and losing the references to those he displaced.. OP, please show us the actual code you use for putting the object into the map as well as the code relevant to it.

Comment: Whaa guys. My mate generated the id-s between 1 and 100...thank for advices. I changed the singlethreadexecutor and hashmap to the right ones. 
BTW this sentence led me to the solution: " please show us the actual code you use for putting the object into the map"